# IE memory leak - settimeout, repeatedly setting innerHTML

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks, settimeout, innerhtml

I have an application which redraws a portion of the page every 60 seconds. The redraw causes major memory leaks in IE.

I tried using both settimeout/setinterval to set the redraw timer.

I also tried many of the tips suggested like

- setting innerHTML = '' instead of using jquery remove/empty.
- Removing all event handlers before redrawing HTML.
- Deleting all child nodes before emptying the parent container.
- Setting outerHTML to clear instead of innerHTML

In spite of all these I can see a big memory leak. MS KB article seems to indicate that IE 8 is inherently leak and we need to apply a hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975623

But, I have seen this issue in IE7 as well and in firefox to a very small level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Suchin

Comment: So you know that leak is still in IE9

Answer (score 0):

All the options you mentioned are worth the shot, have you also tried adding the DOM element first, and then setting the innerHTML later?

Here is an example
http://ecmascript.stchur.com/blogcode/ie_innerhtml_memleak/noleak.html

And the guy's solution

```
   // Add the element to the DOM first, and /then/ set .innerHTML to 
   // prevent memory from leaking.
   document.body.appendChild(elem);
   elem.innerHTML = str;
```

How did you remove all the handlers? did you use something like Crockford's purge solution?
http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html